# How to create a new column with total number of elements from a column of lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I'm trying to create a new column in a pandas dataframe that shows the total number of items seen in another column comprised of lists like the one in the hashtag and ment column below.

I tried the following but I'm getting an error message.

```
df['hashcount']=df['hashtag'].value_counts()
```

[image]

Comment: It's kinda strange when read *I tried the following but I'm getting an error message.* and you don't see any error message in the question. That said, `[]` looks like a list and lists are mutable so can't be hashed/compared so no `value_counts()`.

Comment: Are you trying to get the value_counts per row within the list OR are you trying to get the value_counts of each unique list within your dataframe? Please see how to ask a pandas question here. Please include input (no images) and desired output (no images): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
df['hashcount']=df['hashtag'].apply(len)
```

This will return the number of elements in each list you have in the column 'hashtag'.